# Cannot display block from template - magento

Tags: magento

I'm calling a block from a template as follows. I'm aware it's not the recommended way but the layout.xml approach is giving me trouble

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('shoppingbasket/options')
                    ->setTemplate('shoppingbasket/cart/item/default/options.phtml')
                    ->setBlockId('options')
                    ->setProduct($_item->getProduct())
                    ->setSelectedOptions($this->getOptionList())
                    ->toHtml() ?>
```

The block gets rendered. Now I'm trying to add it via the layout.xml approach

I've added the block to the layout.xml as follows:

```
<layout>    
    <checkout_cart_index>    
        <reference name="checkout.cart">
            <block type="shoppingbasket/options" template="shoppingbasket/cart/item/default/options.phtml" name="options"></block>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>shoppingbasket/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </checkout_cart_index>
</layout>
```

and I'm calling the block from the template as follows:

```
 <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('options') ?>
```

The block isn't appearing and I've tried moving the block everywhere in the layout.xml. What am I doing wrong? Also is there a way to pass parameters to the block using the layout.xml approach as I did with

```
->setProduct($_item->getProduct())
                    ->setSelectedOptions($this->getOptionList())
```

Thanks!

Comment: and in what template you are calling this?

Answer (score 0):

you did everything right, except one thing: you should set block alias - "as" attribute of the block.

```
<block type="shoppingbasket/options" template="shoppingbasket/cart/item/default/options.phtml" name="options" as="options"></block>
```

Methods `getChild` or `getChildHtml` use block alias for retrieving block instance from layout.